# Is it possible to add a ok_button to best_in_place with a select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

Question is I would really would like the ability to have a ok_button with my best_in_place that is a select I know it works with a text area or input but, it will not work with a select are there any hack arounds to enable this for a select or any other options. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my view that has the best in place

```
%td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black; color: red'}
  %span.u= best_in_place my_model, :approve_disapprove, :as => :select, :collection => ['Approve', 'Disapprove', 'Pending'], :ok_button => 'Okay'
```

and my application.js that enables the best_in_place

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake by not consuming any coffee today, but I have no idea what you're asking here. You want to use an ok_button with a select? What is it that's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: With best in place for rails you can only use the ok_button feature if its a textarea or input. this however isn't either of those, so my question is how could I write this to have an ok button and a select. biggest thing is with best in place if you edit something it automatically saves but with an ok button it will alleviate some issues im having with users not understanding the concept of no ok button .....lol @MarsAtomic